# Yii2-activedataprovider doesn't fetch data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii2, cactivedataprovider

I use some `$query->andFilterWhere(...)` to create my query.

and can see the final query by `echo $query->createCommand()->rawSql;`

when I copy the final query and past it on phpmyadmin, 2 record fetched but no result found in ActiveDataProvider.

Where is the point that I miss that?!

============================================

This is my code:

```
    $query = Camera::find();
$post = Yii::$app->request->post();
$post2 = array_filter((array)$post);

if( count($post2) >0 ){
    foreach($post2 as $k=>$v){
        $query->andFilterWhere([ 'Like' , $k , $v ]);
    } 
}

if($post['State'] > 0){
    $branches = Branch::find()->joinWith('city')->where('state_id='.((int)$post['State']))->all();
    foreach( $branches as &$v){
        $v = $v->brch_id;
    }
    $query->andFilterWhere([ 'IN' , 'brch_id' , $branches ]);    
}

echo $query->createCommand()->rawSql;

$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query,
]);
```

Comment: Could you post more of your code? It's difficult to answer with this info only.

Comment: Code added. Help please...

Comment: Please add what you are getting in final query. because these details are insufficient to help you. And also please mention what is the post value of Yii::$app->request->post();

Comment: What do you do after create this part of code .. show the rest ..

Comment: Add row query worked with phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was this loop:

```
foreach( $branches as &$v){
    $v = $v->brch_id;
}
```

I just replace it by:

```
$a = [];
foreach( $branches as $v){
    $a[] = (int)$v->brch_id;
}
```

and DONE, Solved!!!!! :|

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have

```
if( count($post2) >0 ){ // that means all fields filled
    foreach($post2 as $k=>$v){
        $query->andFilterWhere([ 'Like' , $k , $v ]);
    }
}
```

And just after that you have a check for `$post['State']` and you are using it for a `joinWith`. I Don't know what kinda search you are using (or what form did you build), but it seems you are searching for `State` in this both models... is that the correct behavior?

If that's correct, can you show us the raw sql query that worked for you, but not with `ActiveDataProvider`?

And can i ask why don't you use a class for this search and extends it from `Camera`?

It would be something similar to this:

```
public $state // fields that you Camera model don't have.

public function search($params){
    $query = Camera::find();
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    if (!($this->load($params) && $this->validate())) {
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    $query->andFilterWhere('like', 'attribute', $this->attribute);
    // same for the others attributes here...

    $query->joinWith(['nameOfRelationWithBranch' => function ($queryBranch) {
        $queryBranch->joinWith(['city' => function ($queryCity) {
            $queryCity->andFilterWhere('state_id', $this->state);
        }]);
    }]);

//echo $query->createCommand()->rawSql;
return $dataProvider;
```

}